# What are the technical difficulties with implementing voting on hardware wallets?

Tags: governance

Why is it so hard to make voting possible for hardware wallets?

What are the technical difficulties to implement that Feature?

Comment: Maybe some additional software needs to be developed by the hardware device manufacturers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main problems with adding new features to hardware wallets is the long update cycle.

Developers can't just upload a new version. A hardware wallet like Ledger Nano series can only get an update once a month, and it has to go through a 3rd party process beforehand.

Therefore, they lag a bit behind in functionality. You don't usually do iterative updates on hardware wallets. Instead, you release one when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Coming soon. While we do not understand the technical hurdles, at least once it has been mentioned that they are close to releasing voting from hardware wallets. Agreed that it would be great and many more will participate if not for a bit of clumsy process of current voting process. Baby steps. :)